# Нужно ли обособлять вводную конструкцию?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

*«И(1) конечно же(2) они классные!»*

Как объяснить расстановку запятых (1) и (2). Работает ли здесь правило о ненадобности запятой при примыкании союза «И» к вводной конструкции; влияет ли на постановку запятых интонация?

Answer (score 1):

***И конЕчно же, // они классные!***

1. Правило: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122

Пункт 6. Между присоединительным союзом (в начале самостоятельного предложения) и вводным словом (сочетанием) запятая обычно не ставится, так как союз тесно примыкает к вводному слову.

2. Интонация соответствует постановке запятой и обозначает подчеркнутую паузу.